# Images are repeating in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented android app which should download images from server and display them in ListView, but very interesting thing occures while images are downloading

As you can see in video pictures which haven't been downloaded yet are represented by those which have been already downloaded. How that can happen? I've thinking about it almost two days.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxY-HAuJO0o&feature=youtu.be

here is my code of ListView adapter.

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParkCinema> {
        private ArrayList<ParkCinema> movieDataItems;   
        private Activity context;

        public MoviesAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ParkCinema> movieDataItems) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, movieDataItems);
            this.context = context;
            this.movieDataItems = movieDataItems;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.movie_data_row, null);
                }

            ParkCinema movie = movieDataItems.get(position);

            if (movie!=null){
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_thumb_icon);
                        String url = movie.poster();

                         if (url!=null) {
                            Bitmap bitmap = fetchBitmapFromCache(url);
                            if (bitmap==null) { 
                                new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView).execute(url);
                            }
                            else {
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            } 
                        } 
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        private LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmapCache = new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>();

        private void addBitmapToCache(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                synchronized (bitmapCache) {
                    bitmapCache.put(url, bitmap);
                }
            }
        }

        private Bitmap fetchBitmapFromCache(String url) {

            synchronized (bitmapCache) {
                final Bitmap bitmap = bitmapCache.get(url);
                 if (bitmap != null) {
                    return bitmap;
                } 
            }

            return null;

        }


    private class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

            private String url;
            private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

            public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
                imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground (String... source) {
                url = source[0];
                Bitmap image;
                try{
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream());
                    return image;
                    }
                catch(Exception e){Log.e("Error", e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace();}
                return null;
                } 


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {       
                addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);
                imageViewReference.get().setImageBitmap(bitmap);               
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit 3:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.movie_data_row, null);
        }
    ParkCinema movie = movieDataItems.get(position);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_thumb_icon);
    if (movie!=null){
                String url = movie.poster();

                    if (url != null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = fetchBitmapFromCache(url);
                        if (bitmap == null) {
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
                            new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView).execute(url);
                        }
                        else {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
                } 

    return convertView;

}
```

Comment: After `ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_thumb_icon);`, add `imageView.setImageBitmap(null);`. What you are seeing is a normal behaviour

Comment: Thanks for answering.
If I'll set null to imageView same thing happens

Comment: sorry! use `imageView.setImageDrawable(null)` or `imageView.setImageResource(0)`

Comment: tried both variants, didn't help :(

Comment: are you adding it in the right place? just after `ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_thumb_icon);`

Comment: I had the same problem and `imageView.setImageBitmap(null);` worked for me. But why is this "normal behaviour"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Aha! I think I may know the issue. Right now, your `getView` method sets your `ImageView` like this:

1. Gets movie object at position
2. Pulls out the movie's thumbnail url
3. Using that url, it tries to find the image in the cache
4. If it finds the image, it sets it
5. If it can't find the image, it starts an async network request to go get it, and sets it after it gets downloaded.

Your issus arises since `ListView` reuses its rows' `View`s. When the first `View` scrolls off the screen, rather than inflate a new one, `ListView` passes the now offscreen row's `View` in as `convertView` for you to reuse (this is for efficiency).

When your `getView` gets a `convertView` that is getting reused, its `ImageView` has already been set from the row that had it before, so you see the old image from the offscreen row's `View`. With your current `getView` process, you check for the new row's image, and it doesn't find it in the cache, it starts a request to download it. While it is downloading, you see the old image until you get the new image.

To fix this, you need to make sure you set every field in the row's `View` immediately, to make sure you don't have any `View`s showing stale data. I would suggest you set the `ImageView` to the default `drawable` resource (you have set in your `R.layout.movie_data_row`) while you wait for the network download to get the image.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.movie_data_row, null);
    }

    ParkCinema movie = movieDataItems.get(position);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_thumb_icon);
    if (movie != null) {
        String url = movie.poster();

        if (url != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = fetchBitmapFromCache(url);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                // Set the movie thumbnail to the default icon while we load
                // the real image
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.movie_thumb_icon);
                new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView).execute(url);
            }
            else {
                // Set the image to the bitmap we get from the cache
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        else {
            // Set the movie thumbnail to the default icon, since it doesn't
            // have a thumbnail URL
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.movie_thumb_icon);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Set the movie thumbnail to the default icon, since there's no
        // movie data for this row
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.movie_thumb_icon);
    }
```

### **-Edit-**

Updated to be even more robust, using your `drawable`. You also have an issue with your `BitmapDownloaderTask`, it does not handle errors/null. Try adding this as well.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) { 
    addBitmapToCache(url, bitmap);
    if (bitmap == null) {
        // Set the movie thumbnail to the default icon, since an error occurred while downloading
        imageViewReference.get().setImageResource(R.drawable.movie_thumb_icon);
    }
    else {
        imageViewReference.get().setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }            
}
```

Comment: Thank you for so detailed response. I've modified code as you told, but the same thing happens :( I think ListView sets convertView to new row object and shows it before reaching the part of code which we have modified now, so it displays old image.

Comment: I have implemeted Pramod J George's suggested method, it solved my problem, but created another one. Now app runs slower in emulator, and I don't like it. Just want to be everything perfect :/

Comment: Pramod J George's suggestion is a hack, it's like smashing through a wall vs using the door. You will get lag when you scroll using that method, because it is not reusing `View`s. Can you edit the question and show the code that you have attempted with my method? I'm feeling like there might be a small piece missing.

Comment: Done! Also I've looked up two examples from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview In both of them images are downloading without lag. I've read the source code, and I think they are using almost the same implementation of adapter as mine, but their code works well :/

Comment: You need to copy my methods **exactly**, you did not completely implement what I suggested the first time. Please copy my methods and paste over yours, and if they do not work, please explain how it is behaving. I have image loading like this working in my applications just fine, so something you are doing must be off.

Comment: I've changed everything as you told and checked it twice. (Edit 3 in my post) But the problem still exists, and some images are flipping 2-3 times while downloading :(

Comment: Ahhh I think what is happening is that you are scrolling faster the `AsyncTask`s can finish, and they aren't being cancelled. So if you scroll and the same row gets reused 3 times and starts 3 network calls, you will see the image get set multiple times since each `AsyncTask` share the same reference to the same `ImageView`, and are setting it when they finish. I am using the google lib for loading/caching images, which appears to handle this issue - https://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/wiki/ImageLoader. Also check out http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/BitmapFun.zip.

Comment: I don't understand the source code of those libs you have provided :( 
There is so much stuff compared to my implementation, and so I can't catch that difference which makes those libs working properly

Comment: This is a complicated issue, which is why Google took the time to make the lib. Basically they handle the case where your image may be done loading, but now the `ImageView` has already been recycled, so they don't set it and you don't see the image changed several times. I checked my source and noticed that check is in there. You would have to implement it yourself, which would require a bit of work. I'd suggest you dig into their example/wiki and use their impl, as it works excellently for me.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. Every time I confused with google answers. May be I will not for next time from yours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i had this issue and implemented lruCache ...i believe you need api 12 and above or use the compatiblity v4 library. lurCache is fast memory but it also has a budget, so if your worried about that you can use a diskcache ...its all described here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

I'll now provide my implementation which is a singleton i call from anywhere like this:

//where first is a string and other is a imageview to load

```
DownloadImageTask.getInstance().loadBitmap(avatarURL, iv_avatar);
```

here's the ideal code to cache and then call the above in getView of an adapter when retrieving the web image:

```
 public class DownloadImageTask {

private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

/* create a singleton class to call this from multiple classes */

private static DownloadImageTask instance = null;

public static DownloadImageTask getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DownloadImageTask();
    }
    return instance;
}

//lock the constructor from public instances
private DownloadImageTask() {

    // Get max available VM memory, exceeding this amount will throw an
    // OutOfMemory exception. Stored in kilobytes as LruCache takes an
    // int in its constructor.
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
            // number of items.
            return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
        }
    };

}

public void loadBitmap(String avatarURL, ImageView imageView) {
    final String imageKey = String.valueOf(avatarURL);

    final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        new DownloadImageTaskViaWeb(imageView).execute(avatarURL);
    }
}

private void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}

/* a background process that opens a http stream and decodes a web image. */

class DownloadImageTaskViaWeb extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTaskViaWeb(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(urldisplay), mIcon);

        return mIcon;
    }

    /* after decoding we update the view on the mainUI */
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Views are reused for performance with Adapters. You should use another approch .
You have to have a class holder which reuse your views. In your case you class should be something like this:

```
   public class MoviesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParkCinema> {
    private ArrayList<ParkCinema> movieDataItems;   
    private Activity context;

    public MoviesAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId,       ArrayList<ParkCinema> movieDataItems) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, movieDataItems);
        this.context = context;
        this.movieDataItems = movieDataItems;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.movie_data_row, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.imageView = (BarImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movie_thumb_icon);
              } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

                  }

        ParkCinema movie = movieDataItems.get(position);

        if (movie!=null){

                    String url = movie.poster();

                     if (url!=null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = fetchBitmapFromCache(url);
                        if (bitmap==null) { 
                            new BitmapDownloaderTask(imageView).execute(url);
                        }
                        else {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } 
                    } 
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap> bitmapCache = new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    private void addBitmapToCache(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            synchronized (bitmapCache) {
                bitmapCache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap fetchBitmapFromCache(String url) {

        synchronized (bitmapCache) {
            final Bitmap bitmap = bitmapCache.get(url);
             if (bitmap != null) {
                return bitmap;
            } 
        }

        return null;


public static class ViewHolder {


        ImageView imageView; 


    }

    }
```

Comment: When getView gets called the first time your views are initialized(inside if (convertView == null) { ). Then, for the next rows the Views are not instantiated anymore but reused. This is the reason why you got your image replicated.

Comment: and what does viewholder do in this situation? It creates new ImageView objests for every row?

Comment: viewholder holds the objects that were created for the first row

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get that.. In my code ImageView object is reused for all rows excluding first, but if I'll use ViewHolder will it change something?

Answer (score 0):

I have spent hours trying to figure this one out as well...Thanks to Steven Byle's solution...
Here is my solution to something similar when a user selects an item from a list:

```
adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);
```

then in the custom adapter:

```
public void setSelectedIndex(int ind)
{
    selectedIndex = ind;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and then finally in the getView method of the adapter:

```
if(selectedIndex!= -1 && position == selectedIndex)
         {
             holder.tab.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
         }
         else{
             holder.tab.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
         }
```

So in conclusion make sure you assign default values

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used Picasso library instead of AsyncTask for downloading image.
[enter link description here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Also write if else condition, that is set null to image if url is not available

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add the images here instead of linking to them. If a link stops working, the answer is lost.

Answer (score -2):

instead of using the convertview object create a new view each time.

```
View localView = ((LayoutInflater)parentscreen.getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(R.layout.activity_list_row, null);
```

By inflating as above.

Comment: Won't this consume much memory?

Comment: Tried your solution, but nothing changed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong,Can you post more detailed example?

Comment: Inflating the row layout every time is bad practice. `ListView` reuses row layouts and passes them in as `convertView`. That part of his code is correct, the issue does not have to do with his inflating code.

Comment: Can you explain why it is bad practice? is there any other solution?