# how to avoid duplicate images added in the listview

Tags: android, image, android-listview

i am doing an app loading currently taken images in the list view, I am able to load the images in the list view,but the problem is the images are repeatedly viewing in the list after 3 items and some tine its view then and there in the imageview.but my need is to add the image in the list when the user took,please help me thanks in advance.  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertview;

```
    try {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (vi == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_trip_list_view_items, null);


            holder.place_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.my_trip_list_view_place_name);

            holder.Day = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.my_trip_list_view_date_time);
            holder.place_images = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.my_trip_list_view_Image_view);

            //*Note svg*//*
            holder. place_images.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            menu_svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.map_2);
            holder.place_images.setImageDrawable(menu_svg.createPictureDrawable());



            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        // images_view = new MyTrip_getmethod();
        String location_name = Location.get(position).toString();
        System.out.println("location_name>>>>>>>>>>>" + location_name);
        holder.place_name.setText(location_name);
        System.out.println("location_name>>>>>>>>>>>" + holder.place_name);

        holder.Day.setText(day.get(position).toString());
        System.out.println(" ### imgFile----" + image);

        holder.place_images.setImageBitmap(image.get(position));


        System.out.println("location_name>>im>>>>>>>>>>>" + holder.place_images);

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: You can refer this following link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412767/images-are-repeating-in-listview][1]

Comment: this example is so complicated please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a problem with listview recycling issue.tO avoid this settag for your imageview with the position parameter of the getview method of your adapter class.

```
try {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int crnposition=position; 
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (vi == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_trip_list_view_items, null);


            holder.place_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.my_trip_list_view_place_name);

            holder.Day = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.my_trip_list_view_date_time);
            holder.place_images = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.my_trip_list_view_Image_view);

            //*Note svg*//*
            holder. place_images.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            menu_svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(context.getResources(), R.raw.map_2);
            holder.place_images.setImageDrawable(menu_svg.createPictureDrawable());



            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
  holder.setTag(crntposition);
  holder.place_images.setTag(crntposition);
        // images_view = new MyTrip_getmethod();
        String location_name = Location.get(position).toString();
        System.out.println("location_name>>>>>>>>>>>" + location_name);
        holder.place_name.setText(location_name);
        System.out.println("location_name>>>>>>>>>>>" + holder.place_name);

        holder.Day.setText(day.get(position).toString());
        System.out.println(" ### imgFile----" + image);

        holder.place_images.setImageBitmap(image.get(Integer.parseInt(imageview.getTag().toString())));`


        System.out.println("location_name>>im>>>>>>>>>>>" + holder.place_images);

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return vi;
} 





and use like `holder.place_images.setImageBitmap(image.get(Integer.parseInt(holder.place_images.getTag().toString())));`
```

Comment: i am using the bitmap for imageview

Comment: do you get that from an array please post your code so that someone can help you here...

Comment: adapter = new MyTrip_listview_Adapter(MyTrip.this, location, Date_Array,imagesview, j, context, arrayplaces);
                        listViewplace.setAdapter(adapter); the above is the adapter,here i have decleared in this location is viewed service every 5min  holder.place_images.setImageBitmap(image.get(position));

Comment: @hari check my edits try to post your code in your question itself.

Comment: i have given my getview method in my adapter class

Comment: Thanks for your reply Like this only I have done, here my images itself is not loading and here i am using Array<Bitmap> to get the images

Comment: no issue ,But,images is not viewing in the list itself.Before i am able to get the images

Comment: I don't know hat's happening there I usually use this way to meet listview issues like repetition.Sorry

Comment: in your codes what is imageview refer to   holder.place_images.setImageBitmap(image.get(Integer.parseInt(imageview.getTag().toString())));`

Comment: oh sorry pls replace with holder.place_images

Comment: while doing this the taken image is not viewing in the listview itself

Comment: did you copy/pasted my code completely?please print the log for System.out.println("image" +image.get(Integer.parseInt(imageview.getTag().toString()))